# What services potentially unsafe in Windows 7 can be disabled?

Tags: windows-7, services

What services windows 7 for domestic users are potentially unsafe that can be disabled without compromising the system, making it the safest and most difficult security breaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very broad question to ask, but I would point you towards the [Microsoft Security Compliance Manager (SCM)](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1866.microsoft-security-compliance-manager-scm-getting-started-en-us.aspx).

From the article:

> **The SCM Console**
>
> The SCM Console provides you with a single point of access to work
>   with the recommended security baselines from Microsoft for your
>   security environment. The console also provides access to supporting
>   documentation to help you make informed decisions about how to
>   customize the security baselines to meet your organization's security
>   requirements.

Looking at the operating system from this perspective is a far better option than deciding to simply shut down services willy-nilly. Windows 7 is complex with many dependencies, and just randomly stopping things without understanding the different possibilities is foolish.

Comment: Yes I understand and thanks for the link, but agrees with me that there are several services in Windows that most home users do not use, example: file sharing, remote desktop, vnc, etc. .. These services are easily exploited with the use of tools, I want to turn over potentially unsafe to use and not not compromise the system.

Comment: I think your intentions are honourable, but misplaced. Any system can be compromised, regardless of the services that are running.

Comment: I have to agree again with you, to the unix system more secure can be invaded. But if you have something I can do to harder the invasion on my system, is better.

Comment: That link above is NSA-approved. It's as hard as you're going to get Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know for Windows 7, but on Win 2000 and Win XP I would disable the server service, the telnet service, the remote desktop.

It is important to make thse services permanently disabled rather than marking them as "manual" because an intruder would be able to start them having only user rights if they are not permanently disabled.